# jQuery recursive load for layout

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a script that loads content from divs with the src attribute set. Once that content is loaded I would like for any divs with the src attribute set from within the loaded content to also load more content etc. I have tried using the on function which seems to work with "action" events such as click, or submit but using on("load", selector does not seem to propagate the event.

This is what I currently have:

```
jQuery("body").on("load", "div[src]", function () {
    jQuery(this).load(jQuery(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: If you succeed I can see this loop forever

Comment: Ideally the code would only be triggered on new elements in the DOM.

Comment: @mplungjan came up with quite a simple solution

Comment: Show us.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no load event on content elements

Here's a simple plugin approach that looks inside each new content load and initializes same plugin on new elements

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.loadMore = function() {
    //iterate all elements in collection
    return this.each(function() {
      //ajax load content for each element instance
      var $el = $(this), url = $el.data('src');

      $el.load(url, function() {
        // new content was loaded...initialize again on applicable new elements
        $el.find('[data-src]').loadMore();
      });

    })
  }
})(jQuery);

// on page load start loading
jQuery(function($) {
  $('[data-src]').loadMore()
})
```

Note use of html5 `data-` attribute for `data-src` attribute instead of using just `src`.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TlFTMFhluaQ43rWcXxzq?p=preview)**</kbd>